# Logistic Regression in scikit-learn predicts higher probability than expected for Text Classification

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, classification, logistic-regression

I am working on a feature aimed at prompting users to attach images based on their recent conversations where images were shared.

If a user attempts to send a message without an image for similar contexts, I've implemented a prediction mechanism using `scikit-learn`. However, I'm encountering an issue where the prediction for the message 'how are you?' returns `0.66`, while it should ideally be than `0.5`.

Here is the code:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

messages = {'Did you receive the image yesterday?': 0,
            'I\'m going to send you a picture of my cat.': 1,
            'I\'m at the beach and I\'m taking a photo of the sunset.': 1,
            'I\'m going to send you a video of my dog playing fetch.': 1,
            'I\'m going to send you a screenshot of my computer screen.': 1,
            'Please find the attachment': 1, 'attached file': 1,
            'attached image': 1, 'attached': 1, 'yesterday?': 1, 'did you receive': 0}

pd_messages = pd.DataFrame({'text': messages.keys(),
                            'has_image': messages.values()})

features = pd_messages['text']
labels = pd_messages['has_image']

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
features_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(features)

model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
model.fit(features_tfidf, labels)

message = "how are you?"
message = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', message.lower())
message_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform([message])

prediction = model.predict_proba(message_tfidf)[:, 1]

print(prediction)
```

Even after adding `'how are you?': 0` to the messages dictionary, the prediction is still above `0.5`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Add More Training Data, otherwise you can use other ML feature engineerings techniques like n-grams or word embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your example:

1. There is class imbalance present which in general is not good when using regression-based models.
2. The training dataset is extremely small.
3. TF-IDF might not be the best choice when extracting conversational context.

Possible solutions:

1. Generate more samples of class 0 until your training set is balanced or use balancing techniques like minority-oversampling or majority-undersampling.

```py
# Add more examples with has_image=0
messages['how are you?'] = 0
messages['hello'] = 0
```

2. Increase the number of training samples.
3. You might want to try out word embeddings.

Comment: thanks for the response. trying out this

Comment: @lalithkumar Did it work? And did it help you?

Comment: increasing training sample is helping